# Node package not install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install node package `canvas` (`npm install canvas -g`), but getting this error:

```
> canvas@1.3.0 install /home/user/WebstormProjects/testing/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

./util/has_cairo_freetype.sh: 4: ./util/has_cairo_freetype.sh: pkg-config: not found
gyp: Call to './util/has_cairo_freetype.sh' returned exit status 0. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules /npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/WebstormProjects/testing/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.3.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/WebstormProjects/testing/npm-debug.log
```

libicu-dev and node-gyp is installed. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From HenryHey who found it from Epistemex

When I encountered the "Package cairo was not found" issue on Ubuntu 12.10, I solved it via: sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev

Immediately afterwards I encountered this error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory, which was solved via: sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev

Lastly, I encountered this issue: gif_lib.h: No such file or directory, and solved it via: sudo apt-get install libgif-dev

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I did everything according to instructions, and now another error. Edited the first message.

Comment: If its a new error, please mark mine as correct and submit a new question instead of editing your post.